# Store user data in Ninject-binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I'm using Ninject in a ASP MVC-website. I'm looking for a way to store user-data (e.g. username, current group, etc) that is used on multiple places in my website, to prevent multiple database-calls accessing the same data in one request.

My idea is to use a class that is bound using InRequestScope, where I can store the user-data. Is this safe to do? Is there a possibility that the class gets mixed up between multiple users, or is this impossible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store these data in session. Also if you use `Membership` & `Roles` class of `System.Web.Security` you can access current user and roles of it by `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` properties and methods such as `Identity` and `IsInRole(string role)`